# Expect script to select options in GRUB menu

Tags: automation, expect, grub

Is it possible to select options in GRUB menu to select appropriate option to boot the device ?

I have a serial connection to the device and I am writing the expect script to send the DOWNARROW key to select the appropriate option in the GRUB menu at bootup. But for some reason it doesn't work out.

```
expect "GRUB loading."
#down arrow
send {^[\[B}

send "\r"
send "\r"
```

Comment: `^[\[B` is probably not what you want to send. Try `send \x1F`

Comment: Atleast in Linux it is ^[\[B for down arrow. I even tried with \x1F and still i am facing the same issue

Comment: Can you somehow see what bytes would be sent if you press the down key?

Comment: I ran autoexpect and it says ^[\[B

Answer (score 1):

After trying multiple methods of issuing a 'down arrow' with `expect`, I managed to get this to work using grub2:

`send \003N`

This sends Ctl+N, which works as a secondary down arrow, seen and explained better here:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/137323/grub2-without-arrow-keys

Answer (score 1):

```
send "\033\[B"
```

works for moving down the menu in grub (`\033` is the `ESC` char)

so then for example

```
send "\033\[B\033\[B\r"
```

will move you down twice and then send a carriage return-- choose third option in menu

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using braces, you don't need to escape the `[`

```
send -- {^[[B}  ;# where "^[" is entered with ctrl-V Esc
```

Or using double quotes, where the open bracket does need to be escaped, but it's easier to type the escape character.

```
send -- "\033\[B"
```

Comment: Even tried the above options ... and seems it is not working. Somehow in grub menu it is not selecting the second option

Comment: Try using `autoexpect` to record a manual session and see what gets produced.

Comment: I tried autoexpect ... where it is using "send {^[\[B}" only